# Creating Objects with jQuery: String Concat or Methods?

Tags: jquery

When dynamically creating DOM objects in jquery is it better to use pure string concatenation or should I use the jquery methods? Which is the more "jQuery way"?

```
var tr = $('<tr/>').addClass('foobar');
// or    $('<tr class="foobar"/>');

tr.append('<td>' + someobj.property + '</td>');
// or ...
tr.append($('<td/>').text(someobj.property));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand it is *faster* to create objects using just strings but sometimes it is just more convenient to use the helper methods. In general, I try to use string concatenation whenever possible since it cuts down on the overhead, but sometimes it just makes more sense to use the jQuery builder methods.

Answer (score 2):

Use whichever way is easiest for you to read.  Personally, I prefer `$('<tr class="foobar"/>')` and `tr.append('<td>' + someobj.property + '</td>');`

Answer (score 2):

According to some [jQuery performance](http://www.artzstudio.com/2009/04/jquery-performance-rules/#limit-dom-manipulation) articles [(2)](http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/03/43439-reasons-to-use-append-correctly), if you're heavily manipulating the DOM by adding/appending, it's best to build everything in one go as a string, then append as a whole to the DOM.

If it's small updates now and then, difference won't be significant.

I personally like using [Resig's awesome micro templating](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/) trick to build the HTML and then append everything in one go.. neat and fast. Easy to modify too.

Comment: That's a pretty old article. I wonder if it is still relevant. Appears as though it is based on jQuery 1.3.

Comment: @patrick. I'm pretty sure the DOM bottleneck is an issue with the browser itself. No updated version of jQuery will improve how crappy IE8 (or less)'s handling of DOM operations is

Comment: Perhaps, but check this out from the [1.4 release notes](http://jquery14.com/day-01/jquery-14) *"`jQuery(“<div>”) jQuery(“<div/>”) and jQuery(“<div></div>”)` All three now use the same code path (using document.createElement), improving performance for `jQuery("<div></div>")`. Note that if you specify attributes, we use the browser’s native parsing (using innerHTML)."* Seems to imply that performance is improved because `createElement()` is used instead of `innerHTML` when able. Would need to test to be sure though.

Comment: @patrick. I don't think that's related. This release note is about various ways to create ONE element. The question relates more to constructing multiple elements and adding them separately to the DOM Vs building a string and adding to the DOM in one operation

Comment: You may be absolutely right. The results would certainly vary between browsers. Also depends on the actual situation. Not much info given in the question. Only point is that there have been optimizations in element creation since 1.3. Not sure if they apply here though.

Answer (score 1):

The last line isn't correct because the `text()` is being called on the `tr`.

Personally, I'd do this:

```
var tr = $( '<tr>', {'class':'foobar'} );
$( '<td>', {text:someobj.property} ).appendTo( tr );
```

or:

```
var tr = $( '<tr>', {'class':'foobar'} )
             .append( $('<td>', {text:someobj.property}) );
```

Answer (score 0):

The more jQuery way would probably be to use the jQuery methods but whether that's the best way for a particular situation depends on what is meant by best.

Using the jQuery methods may be best for readability.

String concatenation, pushing to an array and then joining or using document fragments may be a better way for performance.

One point that should be adhered to depending on whichever way you choose to use, is to build the structure in memory and perform only one insert into the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I tend to go with whatever offers the best performance. I am not a super expert on what that may be, but it seems at though others here have enlightened us to what is, so I would go with what will give you the best performance overall. The last thing you want is something that may run slow because you didn't take optimization into account the first time around.